# How to implement AsRef for a struct containing references

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime

If I have a struct containing a reference like so:

```
struct Struct<'a> {
    reference: &'a str
}
```

How can I implement AsRef for the Struct? I tried this:

```
impl<'a> AsRef<Struct<'a>> for Struct<'a> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &Struct {
        self
    }
}
```

but it fails to satisfy the compiler requirements:

> cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in generic type due to conflicting requirements

Comment: What do you want to do? I'm not sure that `AsRef` is the right trait to use in your situation. You maybe want `Borrow`

Comment: The compiler error is bad. You just need to explicitly specify lifetime parameter for your Struct ***everywhere***. [fn as_ref(&self) -> &Struct`<'a>` { ... }](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8063f314cfdbb60e27e703f2a38e35be).

Comment: @Sahsahae That's an answer, not a comment

Comment: One/two sentence answers are pointless, just like this comment. I'd have to explain why it doesn't work otherwise, and I don't think I can do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `fn as_ref(&self) -> &Struct` the compiler has to infer the (implicit) generic lifetime in the return type and fails to do so. The compiler is expecting a `Struct<'a>` but the signature promises a free parameter. That's why you get

```
      expected fn(&Struct<'a>) -> &Struct<'a>
         found fn(&Struct<'a>) -> &Struct<'_>  // '_ is some anonymous lifetime,
                                               // which needs to come from somewhere
```

The solution is to modify the signature to return `Struct<'a>` instead of `Struct`. Even shorter and more clear:

```
impl<'a> AsRef<Struct<'a>> for Struct<'a> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &Self {  // Self is Struct<'a>, the type for which we impl AsRef
        self
    }
}
```